# how to get epoch time in to milli seconds from Date object in ruby?

Tags: ruby, date, time

In Ruby, I want to convert a date object into a accurate 13 digit epoch time(Similar to how java gives).

So for that function if I give the below input, it should give me the below output
Input : November 16,00:00:00.300 IST
Ouput : 1479234600300

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t = DateTime.now.to_f * 1000; t.round`

Comment: Uhm, why? `to_f` does give milliseconds. `Time.now.to_f => 1479362805.960119`. There are 6 digits after the point, but you need the first three, hence `* 1000` and `round`